# Button onClick() not working when thread is running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, onclicklistener

I am struggling with setting the text of a TextView, so I am now trying to do it with a button push, but when I start the thread from the button `readWeight` the button `updateButton` does not work.

Here are my two button `onClick` methods:

```
readWeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        inputWindow.setText("helloooooooo worldddddd");
        //connector.run();
        System.out.println("********** PRINTING **********");

        // readWeight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+weight+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        inputWindow.setText(weight);
    }
});
```

and here is my method that starts the thread, this method is in another class:

```
public void run() {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            //Log.d("workkkkkk","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$****** printingggggg ******$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
            int counter = 0;
            while (true) {
                counter++;
                try {
                    output = "";
                    //read the data from socket stream
                    //mmInStream != null && counter%10000000 == 1
                    if (mmInStream != null) {
                        mmInStream.read(buffer);
                        for (byte b : buffer) {
                            char c = (char) b;
                            if (c >= ' ' && c < 'z') {
                               // System.out.print(c);
                                output += c;
                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction("com.curie.WEIGHT_RECEIVED");
                        intent.putExtra("Output",output);

                        if (counter % 10 == 0) {

                            System.out.println(counter);

                            //InputActivity.setInputWindowText(output);
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcastSync(intent);

                        }


                    }
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //an exception here marks connection loss
                    //send message to UI Activity
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be very appreciated! thank you.

Comment: You did I/O operation from main thread. It may lead to ANR.

Comment: is there an alternative to I/O operations in the case of receiving a Bluetooth signal?

Comment: You must learn about thread first, and then you can implement IO operations securely.

Comment: the print method that comes after `connector.run()` prints, so wouldn't that mean I don't have an ANR error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
Handler.post()
```

It runs in UI thread, so if it is long action it will block all interface.
To avoid it you should run it in another thread. If you don't want to use something complicated you can try this:

```
mHandler = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run () {
     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run () {
        // place your action here
      }
     });
   }
 }).start();
```

Comment: This still renders me unable to use the interface when the thread is running. how might I run another thread? Should the second thread be in the UI activity?